# Working with a table present in multiple databases from rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails application I want to work with a table which is present in multiple databases. If i define a model then it can be mapped only to a single database. So, how can i work with the same table in the other databases.

Should i create separate models for the same table for each database which i don't think would be DRY or is there a better approach ?

Thanks

Comment: Use postbacks like after_create, before_delete to update external DB

Answer (score 0):

use `establish_connection` to change the database dynamically

Eg:

```
# database.yml
db1:
  host: host1
  database: db1

db2:
  host: host2
  database: db2


Model.establish_connection :db2
```